# What is the right level of abstraction to run cucumber tests?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

```
Given a java web application
And that it has a restful back-end
And serves a single page html/js front-end
When I use cucumber to test my application
Then which layer should I drive my tests through?
```

Possible Options:

1) Domain layer: StepsDefs delegate directly to services and repositories

2) REST layer: StepsDefs delegate to REST client which fires HTTP requests at container deployed app

3) User interface: StepsDefs delegate to web driver such as selenium and manipulate the user interface.

PS) Feel free to write your answer in given-when-then notation :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking 2 separate questions, one in the title and another in the body.

### 1) What is the 'correct' level of abstraction?

Executable specifications should be written in the domain/ubiquitous language that makes sense to all the relevant stakeholders (especially non-technical). Each scenario should usually validate a single behaviour and the text should include only relevant information - redundant or incidental detail should be omitted.

The test for correctness is "are the people reading this scenario interested in it?" If the answer is "yes", you will probably be getting valuable feedback from them. If the answer is "no" then you need to collaboratively refine your domain language and focus on behaviours that do interest them.

You may find that you have various stakeholders that have different interests. That's fine. Separate the scenarios into different feature files, each targeted on a segment of your stakeholders. Think of these as different levels of details within a large printed manual.

Any tests that the technical team want to write that no non-technical stakeholder seems interested in can be written using your favourite "unit" testing framework. You could use Cucumber/Gherkin, but is the cost of maintaining domain language for these test worthwhile? You need to decide.

### 2) How should the StepDefs interact with the application?

This question is orthogonal to 1). And the answer is, as always, it depends. I apply the testing pyramid approach and favour tests that exercise as little of the application as makes sense. If I'm testing the behaviour of a component I'd like to interact just with that component through the simplest interface it presents. As I move up the pyramid, I start testing protocols between components, and finally I'm ensuring that the whole application has deployed correctly and 'hangs together'.

Sometimes the only interface available is the UI. That sucks, but we have to live with it if that's the way the application has *already* been built. This often leads to slow and brittle executable specifications that need significant maintenance. Next time, drive the development from the outside and ensure you have ways of exercising the application underneath the UI.

A technique that @everzet and I arrived at from different directions, is to use tags to alter how StepDefs interact with the application. The domain language remains unchanged, but the tag signals to the test code whether it should interact through the UI, the REST API or direct calls to the code.

He has documented his approach in ["modeling by example"](https://stakeholderwhisperer.com/posts/2014/10/introducing-modelling-by-example). I used the same technique in the opposite direction to [rebuild trust between dev & test](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/3957-dont-you-trust-me-a-technical-approach-to-building-trust-and-consensus) and described in [The Cucumber for Java Book](https://pragprog.com/book/srjcuc/the-cucumber-for-java-book)